# Backbone dangling event callbacks in trigger function

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a `playerWrapper` model which triggers `playing` event like so:

`playerWrapper.trigger('playing')`

Then, in a separate window's view called `popupView`, I listen to the event on `initialize`:

```
this.listenTo(playerWrapper, 'playing', function() {
  doSomething()
});
```

One peculiarity of my app is that it's a chrome extension that is separated into two **windows**, a popup window and a background window. They communicate with each other using chrome runtime methods. The problem I am having is that whenever I close the popup and re-open it, the above `trigger` throws the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

I debugged and pinned it down to Backbone source code's `trigger` and `triggerEvents` functions. `triggerEvents` function takes `events` argument, which is a list of event callbacks. In my case, there should be only one callback in the list. However, every time I re-open the popup, I get a duplicate event callback stacked inside the `events` argument, and that has been causing the problem. I suspected that this was caused from `dangling Backbone views` that are usually referred as `zombie views` so I tried `this.stopListening()` on `popupView.initialize()` function but I had no luck.

Does anyone have insight on this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Why would you call a model a "wrapper" that sounds wrong. Also are you just putting these variables in global window scope? As @kharandziuk says the first param for listenTo is a model, not a string

Comment: Sorry that was just a mistake in writing. I am listening to a model. Also, it makes sense to call it a wrapper in this case because the object is given by a third party API. I am attaching the models to global space because its a chrome extension.. any idea? :)